# Required não funciona (.submit)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Criei um formulário comum e coloquei um `button` em que tive que chamar um JavaScript para uma certa situação e o `button` não poderia ser `type='submit'`. Então o coloquei como `type='button'`, chamei a função do JavaScript e para o submit ser feito, no final da condição, coloquei um `$('#form').submit();`.

Até aí beleza...

O problema é que os campos, em que coloquei como `required`, no HTML não estão sendo mais validados e estão conseguindo passar em branco.

Alguém teria uma solução para esse problema?

Answer (score 1):

Existe um método do HTML5 `checkValidity` que é executado nas validações com submit. Abaixo um exemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#submitButton").click(function(e) {
    var $form = $("#loginform");

    if ( !$form.checkValidity ) {
      alert('Erro!!');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="loginform" class="login-form" action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" required name="_username" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
      <input class="form-control" type="password" autocomplete="off" required name="_password" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <button id="submitButton" type="button" class="btn green pull-right">Enviar </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Outra alternativa seria você utilizar a lib [Jquery.validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/), acho mais seguro e mais customizável do que a validação do HTML5. Veja outro exemplo com o mesmo formulário:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#loginform").validate({
    rules: {
      _username: {
        required: true
      },
      _password: {
        required: true
      }
    },
  });

  $("#submitButton").click(function(e) {
    var $form = $("#loginform");

    if ( $form.valid() ) {
      alert('Sucesso!!')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="loginform" class="login-form" action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" required name="_username" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
      <input class="form-control" type="password" autocomplete="off" required name="_password" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <button id="submitButton" type="button" class="btn green pull-right">Enviar </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer um validação de campos ao fazer o submit validando os campos:

```
$( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    var campo = $("#campo").val;
    if(campo == "") {
        console.log("preencha o campo");
        return false;
    }
})
```

Caso tenha mais que um campo, pode ser utilizado o each

```
$( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    $(".campo").each(function() {    
        if ($($this).val() == '') { 
            console.log("preencha o campo");
            return false;
        }
     }    
});
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: obrigado pela sugestão sabrinab, mas eu precisaria de uma maneira sem usar o js para a validação, gostaria de fazer funcionar através desses requires.